# wordpress widget showing white text, can't change it to black?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, styles

I used a free theme from someone : Olsen Light. And I want to add an archive to my sidebar. When the archive is displayed as just text, it is in black. When I change the widget option to dropdown, it's white...

I've been looking in the style CSS, nothing has color:white of #fff in it, only background-colors are white.

**Is there a way I can use an overwriting style class that I put in the 'additional CSS' so that it appears black? I've tried widget-9 { color: black !important; but it doesn't work. Maybe anyone can click *inspect element* to see the css and html and tell me how I can fix this please?**

Here is the example on my blog : www.oihanevalbuenaredondo.be
I've put both archive styles at the bottom of my sidebar

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the elements inside the `aside` for your archives are being wrapped in `<b>` elements set to `color: white;`.

[image]

Add this code, and you should be good:

```
.widget_archive * {
  color: #111 !important;
}
```

I put `#111` but you can use whatever color.

Comment: @Oihane No problem! If I solved your problem, please hit "Accept answer". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting, I've found out it has 3 `<b style="color: white">` inside each other inlined, but none of them has `!important`, so you may override it in a custom style. I see you have a style.css. Try adding this:

```
aside.widget-9 h3 b {
    color: black !important; /* your color */
}
```